# Ignoring horizontal scrolling while scrolling vertically

Tags: 13.10, mouse, touchpad, multi-touch, mouse-scroll

I use two-finger scrolling. 
I would like to enable horizontal scrolling using dconf Editor but when I do, every time I scroll vertically, if I happen to move horizontally even a little, it is detected and results in a horizontal scroll.

On an old mac I had some time ago there was an option to ignore the minor axis of movement and respond only to the major axis of the finger movement. Is this possible on Ubuntu?

Comment: any way around?